# Test if enum is part of a set - with high performance

Tags: swift

I will be receiving many rapid status codes from a network. The status code will be used to initialize an enum by matching it against its rawValue:

```
enum Animal: Int {

    case cockerSpaniel = 10 //dog
    case labrador = 20 //dog
    case beagle = 30 //dog

    case hamster = 40 //rodent
    case rat = 50 //rodent
    case mouse = 60 //rodent

}
```

But sometimes I need to ignore the status code if the rawValue isn't part of a particular group:

```
enum AnimalType {
    case dog //all the rawValues associated with dogs
    case rodent //all the rawValues associated with rodents
}
```

Is there some performant mechanism whereby I can group related enums and test if the enum created from a rawValue matches a group?

Of course I could always do this with a dictionary or array:

```
let dogs: [Int: Animal] = {
     var dict = [Int : Animal]()
     dict[Animal.cockerSpaniel.rawValue] = Animal.cockerSpaniel
     dict[Animal.labrador.rawValue] = Animal.labrador
     dict[Animal.beagle.rawValue] = Animal.beagle
     return dict
}()
```

But then I lose the type checking of having an actual enum for the set of dogs.

Comment: "But then I lose the type checking of having an actual enum for the set of dogs." ???

Comment: I'm not sure why you're working with raw values so much. The whole point of enums is to abstract away raw values, rather than just acting like a bunch of static variables (which is essentially what enum cases are, under the hood). Once you've used initialized your enum value from your status code, you shouldn't have to use raw values anymore

Comment: Because I'm getting status codes over the network and I have to first determine the message type from raw bytes.

Comment: That's fine... "Once you've used initialized your enum value from your status code, you shouldn't have to use raw values anymore". I.e., if you were to make a dict of enums, there's no reason to make the keys be the int raw values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I would do, if I understand the question correctly:

```
enum Animal: Int {
    case cockerSpaniel = 10 //dog
    case labrador = 20 //dog
    case beagle = 30 //dog

    case hamster = 40 //rodent
    case rat = 50 //rodent
    case mouse = 60 //rodent

    enum AnimalGroup {
        case dog
        case rodent
    }

    var group: AnimalGroup {
        switch self {
            case .cockerSpaniel, .labrador, .beagle: return .dog
            case .hamster, .rat, .mouse: return .rodent
        }
    }
}

let statusCode = 10

 guard let animal = Animal(rawValue: statusCode) else {
    fatalError("Invalid status code")
}


if animal.group == .dog {
    print("\(animal) is a dog.")
}
```

Comment: Works very nicely. Did a test with 1,000, 000 iterations and got excellent performance over my data set (< 1.5s)

Comment: @MH175 If you're really performance constrained, you should also compare a few alternate implementations of the `group` computed property: **1)** Store a `Dictionary` statically on the `Animal` struct, and do a look up. I suspect this is what the compiler optimists too, but it's worth comparing. **2)** Linear search through an array, which is ordered by case probability. If there's a huge variation (e.g. one case accounts for 50% of all values encountered), then this may be the fastest.